# mysql_num_rows give unexpected result

Tags: php, mysql

I've got the following function:

```
public function already_tweeted($tweet){
        return mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `retweeted` WHERE `tweet`='$tweet'"));
    }
```

Pretty straightforward. It checks whether a tweet already exists in the database.

The table had the following records:

```
id  user    tweet
3       You should retweet this too
2       Retweet this
```

(user is empty for now)

This code:

```
$db_reader = new database_reader;
$already_tweeted = $db_reader->already_tweeted($tweet);
print $tweet . ". Already: ";
var_dump((bool) $already_tweeted);
print "<br>";
```

Gives the following output:

```
You should retweet this too. Already: bool(false) 
Retweet this. Already: bool(true)
```

I'm pretty much stuck here.
When I run SELECT * FROM `retweeted` WHERE `tweet`='You should retweet this too' in phpmyadmin I get 1 row back.

Comment: From where comes the data you have in `$tweet`? Is it possible that it contains invisible chars like a `\n` or double spaces?

Comment: The data comes from twitter (the replies to my account). That whas what I though, but I checked the char count (\n would show up as a char right, or at least print a new line when used by print or var_dump) and I use trim, so no doubles spaces.

Comment: `\n` will only be shown in the sourcecode view of your browser, not in the rendered output. `trim()` will ONLY remove leading and trailing whitespaces. Something like double spaces inside your string are not affected (otherwise you would have lost ALL spaces and not only the doubled)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check what is the value in **$tweet**

similar problem

- http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/875805-mysql_num_rows-argument-not-being-recognized-any-help-would-appreciated

Also change this line to be safe

```
return mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM retweeted WHERE tweet ='{$tweet}'"));
```

Comment: The value of $tweet is correct, that was the first thing I checked. The recourse is valid.

Comment: its seems every thing is good beside out put, can you put more codes.

Comment: can you output using this echo "<pre>"; print_r($already_tweeted);

Comment: Why `print_r($already_tweeted)`?? We already know the value of `$already_tweeted`...

Comment: This solved it though. I guess he meant  echo "<pre>"; print_r($tweet);
$tweet does have double spaces, that for some reason aren't printed/ removed by trim

Answer (score 0):

`return mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("blah-blah"));` is a dirtiest way to run a query.
make a helper function instead of this horror.

`mysql_num_rows()` is a dirtiest way to count rows, `SELECT count(*)`  wuery should be used instead.

```
//put this function to your function library
function dbgetvar($query){
  $res = mysql_query($query);
  if (!$res) {
    trigger_error("dbget: ".mysql_error()." in ".$query);
    return FALSE;
  }
  $row = mysql_fetch_row($res);
  if (!$row) return NULL;
  return $row[0];
}
public function already_tweeted($tweet){
  $tweet = mysql_real_escape_string($tweet);
  return dbgetvar("SELECT count(*) FROM `retweeted` WHERE `tweet`='$tweet'"));
}
```

Comment: Still no luck

You should retweet this too. Already: string(1) "0" 
Retweet this. Already: string(1) "1"

Comment: @Tim it doesn't matter. My answer not about your problem but about your code. As for your problem - just compare these strings. mysql_num_rows() has nothing to do here

Comment: Yeah, your code is way cleaner, thanks. This is still very weird though